# Sequence $(a_n)$ s.t $\sum\sqrt{a_na_{n+1}}<\infty$ but $\sum a_n=\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am looking for a positive sequence  $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{a_na_{n+1}}<\infty$ but  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n>\infty$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Consider, for example, $a_{2n-1}=1$ and $a_{2n}=2^{-n}$.

Comment: Post it as an answer.

Comment: Note that there can't be a decreasing sequence with this property since if $0<a_{n+1}<a_n$ then $a_{n+1}<\sqrt{a_{n}a_{n+1}}<a_n$ so $\sum a_n$ converges iff $\sum \sqrt{a_na_{n+1}}$ converges (for decreasing $a_n$.)

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n>\infty$ is a rather stringent condition...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest example I can think of is $\{1,0,1,0,...\}$. If you want your elements to be strictly positive, use some fast-converging sequence such as $n^{-4}$ in place of the zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=1+(-1)^n+\epsilon^{2n}$ for $0<\epsilon<1$.  Then $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_n=+\infty$ and  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{a_na_{n+1}}<\infty$.

Comment: That's not a positive sequence, but something close to it can be used.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I improviment my answer.